# Programmatic users login

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, servlets, jboss, wildfly

I have the classic form based authentication setup in my web.xml file:

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>AccessoRiservato</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>webResourceCollectionReserved</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
            <role-name>guest</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Pubblico</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>webResourceCollectionFree</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/login.htm</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.htm</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login.htm</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>    
</login-config>
```

I'm correctly redirected to my login.xhtml page:

```xhtml
<h:form>
  <h:outputLabel for="j_username" value="Nome Utente:"/>
  <h:inputText value="#{sessioneController.username}" id="j_username" size="20"/>

  <h:outputLabel for="j_password" value="Password:"/>
  <h:inputText value="#{sessioneController.password}" id="j_password" size="20"/>

  <h:commandButton action="#{sessioneController.login}" value="Login" />
</h:form>
```

I'd like to check by myself whether user is valid or not:

in case of success, how can I say to the container (JBoss 8 - Wildly in this case) "hey, authenticate this user please!". I cannot create a realm unfortunately.

Comment: Should be done by using the `request.login(userName, password)` method. What is put into this method - `sessioneController.login()` (as indicated by `#{sessioneController.login}`)?

Comment: yes... I tried it. But request.login(u,p) gives me login failed error. I mean, I think that is going to lookup up for users in a realm... but I don't want to use one! I need to implement security check by myself

Comment: Without a realm, this may need to be implemented all by hand - perhaps avoiding the form based authentication in its entirely. Is there any serious business constraint about not creating a JDBC realm? :)

Comment: My users are stored in mongodb